# How to show the printable PDF document with in the browser?

Tags: java, windows, firefox, pdf, pdf-generation

I want show the printable document directly with in the browser when I clicked on print button in my application. I already checked the 'Display PDF in browser' in adobe reader preferences and other PDF files are also being opened in my browser other than that my printable documents. Can you please suggest me

Thanks,
Vara Kumar PJD

Comment: is it a custom application you developed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that PDF sent as response when clicken on print button has correct MIME type (application/pdf). THis will allow browers to recognize it as PDF content and handle it as you want.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type This is supported in Internet Explorer, shown in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(v=vs.85).aspx (Thought some links would help).  I don't know if this is supported in WebKit, but for firefox, support depends on having the right plugin that supports that mimetype, so it's highly likely that it works there.

Comment: I already set the response MIME type as 'application/pdf', But it is not showing the document in browser.